# Unix Shell Scripting removing - from file

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, tr

I have a file containing following info

```
job, cost_code, laborcost,materialcost       
202-12-21, 23-94-23, **110.00-**, 120.04    
204-12-21, 23-93-23, 520.00, **120.04-**    
204-12-12, 24-93-23, 155.00, **120.04-**
```

There are few problem records specifically ones which have a -sign at the end of the line (marked with `**` which isn't really there in the file).

I am trying to remove the - sign with regex but i am having trouble matching only the amount ones which have a problem.

Comment: `tr` is not suitable for this, it can only be used to remove or replace `-` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this command removes dashes at end of line

```
sed s'/-$//'
echo "204-12-21, 23-93-23, 520.00, 120.04-" | sed s'/-$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i~ 's/\([0-9]\)-,/\1,/g;s/-$//' input.csv
```

The first expression finds a digit followed by `-,` and replaces it by the digit and comma; the second expression removes dashes at ends of lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate it

Comment: for some reason the command is not working for end of the line item, I tried the different variations but still it is not working any thoughts ?

Comment: Works for me. Please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/-(,|$)/\1/g' file
```

Remove a hyphen before a comma or a hyphen from the last field of a line.